# com.google.gson.JsonObject cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonArray

Tags: json, casting, arrays

I have some trouble with parsing a JSON response. The response data:

```
{
    "deal": {
        "categorie": {
            "description": "Offres Shopping",
            "idcategorie": "1",
            "nom": "Shopping"
        },
        "conditions": "2 personne au plus",
        "dateAjout": "2013-01-07T00:00:00+01:00",
        "dateExp": "2013-01-31T00:00:00+01:00",
        "description": "nuit dans un hotel 5 etoile",
        "heurexp": "12",
        "iddeal": "1",
        "minutesexp": "30",
        "prestataire": {
            "adresse": "Qu zohour 44",
            "codePostale": "12600",
            "description": "Hotel 5 etoiles",
            "idprestataire": "1",
            "nom": "Hotel ronald",
            "pays": "France",
            "telephone": "99999999",
            "ville": "Brest"
        },
        "prix": "80.0",
        "prixHabituel": "200.0",
        "tags": "hotel",
        "titre": "Nuit 5 etoiles"
    }
}
```

When trying to parse this response to a `List<Deal>` I get this exception:

> com.google.gson.JsonObject cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonArray

This is the code that I am using for the parse:

```
if (reponse != null && !reponse.isEmpty()) {
System.out.println(reponse);

Gson g = new Gson();
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject jObject = parser.parse(reponse).getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray jArray =  jObject.getAsJsonArray("deal");  // here goes the Exception
for (JsonElement elem : dealArray) {
deals.add(g.fromJson(elem, Deal.class));
}

    System.out.println(deals.toString());
    return "success";
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `deal` is not a JSON array, its a JSON object. Hence the exception. A JSON array, for reference, would look more like this:

```
"deal" : [{"attr" : "value"}, {"attr" : "value"}]
```

Comment: yes but when i call   jsonObejct.getAsJsonArray("deal") i want to get the JsonArray i have this exception

Comment: I'm not sure how to break this down further, you can't get a JSON array from your object, because there is no array in it. There is literally no array in the entirety of the JSON you posted. Are you, perhaps, trying to access the ***attributes*** of `deal`?

Comment: yes but i use the google library for json Gson & it's offer that possibility transform a jsonObject to an JsonArray but i don't know why i have this error

Comment: Ok, oblige me here. Before doing the conversion, add this line to your code, and tell me the result - `System.out.println("Is Array: " + jsonObject.get("deal").isJsonArray());`

Comment: I want to convert the JsonObject to a JsonArray to create my object usin new Gson().from(JsonElement,Deal.class)

Comment: I have similar problem where "deal" is json object and inside that I have another "deal" as json array. Somwhat like this - {
 "deal": {
  "deal": [{
   "attr": "value"
  }, {
   "attr": "value"
  }]
 }
} How to handle code here. @Perception